# MATLAB and Objective-C in Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, text-editor

Is there a way to set Sublime Text 2 (running under OSX) so that it can identify MATLAB (.m) files and Objective-C (.m) files automatically? Meaning that ST2 would be able to differentiate between each one and apply it's special syntax highlighting rules. I have already seen this behavior in the all mighty VIM and Emacs.

Comment: How does VI do it? Is it reading embedded comments for hints?

Comment: I seem to recall that Text Mate would be able to differentiate between those two files using a "first line hint" %matlab at the beginning of all your MATLAB files. There are a few rules that a file could be subjected to to test it's origin. I don't really know how does VI do it but it freaking works :O ... problem is I'm beginning to like ST2.

Comment: I can't find any way to give ST2 hints. Cmd-Shift-P to bring up the pallet and then type `Set Syntax` and pick the syntax is all I've got, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at /Users//Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Matlab.sublime-package. It's a simple ZIP file containing a bunch of XML (Plist) files.

In the [Sublime Doc for syntax definitions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) you'd be able to find a documentation of how to create (and edit) syntax definitions.

For an example have a look at the perl syntax definition, it contains a key named "firstLineMatch" which is not used in the Matlab syntax definition. But you could add one and create a file magic for/in your Matlab files.

**Update :** I just gave it a go and it doesn't seem to work. Do be fair TextMate can't do it either.

**Update 2 :** After some more investigation: The question about `firstLineMatch` came up in the [Sublime Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1974). The file extension is taking precedence over `firstLineMatch` right now. So there's not much that can be done. With `firstLineMatch` working you could do nice things. And this would mean that no file magic would be necessary since the syntax of Obj-C and Matlab files is different.

Comment: Nice bit of sleuthing.

Comment: Yeah, I know that TextMate cannot do this but oh well, I guess I will have to wait for an update and see if this ever gets fixed, because I really hate when those two files get messed up. I currently have it default to highlight the MATLAB's syntax but every now and then I jump and see some Objective-C files outside from Xcode. Because Xcode is a mess when opening external files whilst working in a project.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `Matlab.tmLanguage` change it to

```
<key>fileTypes</key>
<array>
    <!-- Actually, it's generally .m, but that's taken by Objective-C. It needs an entry to show up in the syntax list. -->
    <string>m</string>
    <string>matlab</string>
</array>
```

and remove it from `ObjC.tmLanguage`

Comment: Hello Charley, I did this though I didn't see any difference. Are you able to see this working? Are you able to open MATLAB and Objective-C files with their proper colorings? thanks